# Data on server side indefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send some json from a webpage to a node server.

On the client side I have:

```
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/bb", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello, server!" }),
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello"}));
```

I can see { message: "Hello"} on the browser console.

I have the following code in my node app:

```
// POST route
app.post('/bb', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Assuming you're receiving JSON data in the request body
        const newData = await req;
        // Process the new data here
        console.log('Received new data:', newData);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data received successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started on port 3000'));
```

On the server side I see

```
Received new data: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't actually reproduce the problem, logging `newData` gives **lots** of information. I'm assuming you made a mistake transcribing the code and `const newData = await req;` was `const newData = await req.body;` (note that this isn't a promise so `await` is pointless here).

Answer (score 0):

look here do  it like me

```
fetch('http://localhost:5500/Communication', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },  
  method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
     
       name: 'daaa',
      
       }),
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it change the **result on the server** where the body is logged as `undefined`? (Hint: It won't. You've misunderstood the question)

Comment: (Specifically, you've added a `'Accept': 'application/json',` request header, but this is pointless because the server does not do any content negotiation, and you've added some code to decode the JSON response from the server and look at it, which doesn't address the problem the question is asking about).

Comment: The answer in my case was adding "app.use(express.json());   "